# PHP DOMXpath Undefined Variable Error

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I have an XML file set up like so

```
<feeds><feed id="">
<headline></headline>
<author></author>
<datetime></datetime>
<link></link>
<description></description>
</feed></feeds>
```

I am trying to Xpath to extract the attributes from one element, using the elements "id" but I am get an undefined variable error for each attribute. Here is the current script I am trying to use.

```
function extractText($tag) {
foreach ($tag as $item) {
  $value = $item->nodeValue;
}
return $value;
}
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->load("newsfeed/newsfeed.xml");
$id = $_POST['id'];

$domx = new DOMXPath($doc);
$feed = $domx->query("feeds/feed[@id='$id']");
foreach ($feed as $theid) { 
$h_array = $theid->getAttribute('headline');
$headline = extractText($h_array);

$a_array = $theid->getAttribute('author');
$author = extractText($a_array);

$l_array = $theid->getAttribute("link");
$link = extractText($l_array);

$i_array = $theid->getAttribute("image");
$image = extractText($i_array);

$d_array = $theid->getAttribute("description");
$description = extractText($d_array);

$da_array = $theid->getAttribute("datetime");
$datetime = extractText($da_array);
```

If anyone could help me out or at least point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching the child nodes (`headline`, 'author', ..) as attributes. DOMElement::getAttribute() will always return a scalar value, the value of an attribute node. The only attribute node in your example XML is `id`. So you need to fetch the child nodes by name.

I suggest using `DOMXpath::evaluate()`. It can return scalar values from an Xpath expression.

```
$xpath->evaluate('string(headline)', $feed);
```

`headline` will fetch all child nodes with that name for `$feed`. The Xpath function `string()` casts the first node into a string, returning its text content or an empty string.

This works with complex Xpath expressions, too. Because the casting is done in Xpath you can avoid a lot of conditions that validate the return value. Depending on the Xpath expression you will always know if you will get a node list or a scalar.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<feeds>
  <feed id="123">
    <headline>Headline</headline>
    <author>Author</author>
    <datetime>Someday</datetime>
    <link>Url</link>
    <description>Some text</description>
  </feed>
</feeds>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$id = '123';

$feedList = $xpath->evaluate("/feeds/feed[@id='$id']");
foreach ($feedList as $feed) {
  var_dump(
    [
      'headline' => $xpath->evaluate('string(headline)', $feed),
      'author' => $xpath->evaluate('string(author)', $feed),
      'link' => $xpath->evaluate('string(link)', $feed),
      'image' => $xpath->evaluate('string(image)', $feed),
      'description' => $xpath->evaluate('string(description)', $feed),
      'datetime' => $xpath->evaluate('string(datetime)', $feed),
    ]
  ); 
}
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  ["headline"]=>
  string(8) "Headline"
  ["author"]=>
  string(6) "Author"
  ["link"]=>
  string(3) "Url"
  ["image"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["description"]=>
  string(9) "Some text"
  ["datetime"]=>
  string(7) "Someday"
}
```